# Neighborhood deformation retract for the image of a curve

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

Consider a Manifold $M$ without boundary. Now consider a smooth curve $c:[0,1]\rightarrow M$, where we have that $c(0)\neq c(1)$. I was wondering if we could find a neighborhood $V$ of the image of $c$ in $M$ such that $V$ has the same homotopy type has the image of $c$?

Now this reminds alot of tubular neighborhoods , however in this case we might not have that $c([0,1])$ is a submanifold of $M$ , and even if this werer the case since $c(0)\neq c(1)$ this could be a manifold with boundary and hence it wouldn't be a neat submanfiold of $M$, and hence we don't know if we have the existence of a tubular neighborhood.

So I would like to know if it's possible to find such a neighborhood ? Or if there are some conditions I can put on the curve $c$ such that this is possible ?

Any insight is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

No in general. Such an open set might not exist even if $\gamma$ is immersed. As an example, let $\gamma : [-1, 1] \to \mathbb R^2$ satisfies

$$\gamma (t) = \begin{cases} \left( t, \sin (1/t) e^{-1/t}\right), & t\in (-1/4, 1/4) \\
(t-1/2, 0), & t\in (1/3, 2/3)
\end{cases}$$
and otherwise $\gamma(t)$ is outside a fixed ball $B_1$ centered at the origin with $\gamma'(t) \neq 0$.

Let $V$ be any open set containing the image $\Gamma$ of $\gamma$. If $r: V\to \Gamma$ is a retraction, let $B$ be an open ball centered at the origin so that $B \subset V \cap B_1$. Then $r|_B : B\to B\cap \Gamma$ is a retraction, which is not possible since $B\cap \Gamma$ has nontrivial fundamental group (indeed, it still has infinitely many holes).